# How can I highlight local Committed code in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

What I want is to set Intellij that way so that the code I commit locally to git(before I submitted it) would be highlighted, so that I can track my own progress.

The best option would be to highlight the file name and the row where the changes occurred.

The file name highlighting would do too.

Answer (score 1):

After some searching and even thinking of creating a plugin for if I have found that such a plugin exists.

It's called  **[Git Scope](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10083-git-scope)** and it works quite well, just set the scope to compare against Master.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following commands:

1. "Git | Commit" The window with the list of changed files will appear. Double-click the file name to preview the changes. If the window was accidentally closed, reopen it by "View | Tool windows | Commit"
2. Finish the preview and click "Commit" to save changes locally.
3. When you are ready to push to remote, use the "Git | Push" menu item.
   You can unite steps 2 and 3 by clicking the "Commit and push" button.

Comment: This is not relevant, I want the files to be highlighted in the project as I work on it, not view the changes in a different window.

Comment: They are highlighted already, by default newly added files are green, files changed since the last commit are blue, unchanged files are black (foreground text color). You may change the color schema at "Settings | Version Control | File status colors".

Comment: I agree with everything you said, but what I want is to highlight the things that are committed, lets say in another color.

Comment: Check "Settings | Version Control | File status colors", you can customize the color here. By default, "Up to date" (committed) files are black, but you can change that.

Comment: Hmm looks like the right direction, I will check it out, But I expect it would color everything except what is in the change lists and not only what is committed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I found a solution, see my answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70755069/how-can-i-highlight-local-committed-code-in-intellij-idea/70914585#70914585

Answer (score 0):

You can follow either what @nadia suggests, or you can install ***git gui*** too.
When you want to see the progress or changed file names, just run ***git gui*** on same directory. the new pop-up window will be opened with old and new contents

Comment: I want the files to be highlighted in the project as I work on it, opening another program to lookup changes is not very practical...